# Digital Electronics Simulator

Tags: simulation

What online tool can I use to tinker with circuit boards / dimmers / buzzers etc?

I'm wanting to learn more about electronics without spending too much time & money on buying parts I'll only use once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try CircuitLab to help you get started.

https://www.circuitlab.com/

Here is an example with a Piezzo:

https://www.circuitlab.com/circuit/6syafk/bjt-audio-amplifier/